# Conversion from jQuery into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a script:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" value="" id="input1">
    <input type="text" value="" id="input2">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<img id="image" src="http://mydomain.com/empty.gif" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var val1 = $("#input1").val();
        var val1 = $("#input2").val();
        $("#image").attr("src", "http://mydomain.com/image?val1="+val1+"&val2="+val2);
    });
});
</script>
```

How would it look like if written in JavaScript?

Comment: I'm being somewhat pedantic, but...jQuery is Javascript, what you have written is perfectly valid Javascript it just happens to depend on jQuery. What you're asking for is a non-jQuery dependant version.

Comment: Please use proper indenting when submiting your code.

Comment: I think you made a mistake: you're declaring `val1` twice.

Comment: It *is* Javascript (using some functions brought into scope by the jQuery library). **jQuery is _not_ a language**.

Comment: Can't he just add "plain" to the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img id="image" src="http://mydomain.com/empty.gif" />
<script>
window.onload = function() { // Not all browsers support DOMContentLoaded
  document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function() {
     var val1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
     var val2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
     document.getElementById("image").src="http://mydomain.com/image?val1="+val1+"&val2="+val2;
     return false;
   };
};
</script>
```

If you NAME the fields you can use

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function() {
     document.getElementById("image").src="http://mydomain.com/image?val1="+this.input1.value+"&val2="+this.input2.value;
     return false;
   };
};
```

You MAY want to escape the two values

Comment: You miss `return false;`. Moreover, you're waiting for `onload`, not `DOMContentLoaded`, etc. ;-)

Comment: @Marcel: I already fixed the return false and DCL is not supported by a lot of browsers

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to nit-pick a bit about this code not being *exactly* equivalent to the OP's (and to make him aware of the uses of frameworks).

Comment: But in IE8, jQuery would convert DOMContentLoaded to onload, no?

Comment: +1 for the de-jQueryizing. -1 for not fixing the OP's misconception.

Comment: Re IE8: not only that, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L438-458

Comment: @Tom - what misconception? remember Clarke's 3rd law

Comment: @mplungjan: The misconception that jQuery is not Javascript, that jQuery is its own language, and/or that there is any such thing as "jQuery syntax" just because many scripters hadn't seen proper JS syntax before they started using jQuery (which effectively mandates it).

Comment: But I completely agree. jQuery seems like a language on its own. If one is used to simple/core JS, jQuery does in fact come across as a completly different language. I have been using JS since 1996 and have just recently started using jQuery. I mess up things like .val() and .attr() all the time.